How do I italicize the variable "s" in the following equation?
The referee of my manuscript has asked for the letter 's' in the following euqation to be italicized.
From search, I found that in order to italicize math in an equation, I must use \mathit.
The following snippet shows what I did:
\begin{equation}
\label{radEQ2}
I_\omega(x,y) = \int_0^{s(x,y)} j_\omega (s') e^{- \int_{s'}^{s(x,y)} \alpha_\omega (s^\dprime) ds^\dprime} ds'
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{radEQ}
I_\omega(x,y) = \int_0^{\mathit{s}(x,y)} j_\omega (\mathit{s}') e^{- 
\int_{s'}^{\mathit{s}(x,y)} \alpha_\omega (s^\dprime) d\mathit{s}^\dprime} d\textit{s}'
\end{equation}

This is how the equations got rendered though:

Hence the letter 's' did not get italicized i.e \mathit did not work. How do I get the letter 's' to get italicized?

Can you complete your code to create a compilable example? What should the italicised s look like given that the s already looks like an italicised s?

just s will produce math italic s (as used for x and y)  \mathit{s} produces the s from the text italic font which looks similar but isn't normally not used for single letter variables. Both though are italic. Please clarify your question. compare with \mathrm{s} to see a non-italic s.

@DavidCarlisle Too many 'not's?

Since the letters “s” are in italics, my guess is that the referee wants something like

This is “script”, rather than italic.
You can import the symbol from the BOONDOX family.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{BOONDOX-cal}{\skewchar\font =45 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{BOONDOX-cal}{m}{n}{ <-> BOONDOX-r-cal}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ws}{}{\text{\usefont{U}{BOONDOX-cal}{m}{n}s}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{radEQ}
I_\omega(x,y) =
\int_0^{\ws(x,y)} j_\omega (\ws') e^{- \int_{\ws'}^{\ws(x,y)}
  \alpha_\omega (\ws'') d\ws''} d\ws'
\end{equation}

\end{document}


I changed \dprime into '', which is simpler
